# Expose TypeScript's type definitions to JSDoc

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

I have the following code, of which, TypeScript is happy with. It correctly sees that `RequestInit` as the options to a `fetch` request. I also have the ESLint JSDoc plugin active with `no-undefined-types` enabled. When I run ESLint against this code I get the following error `The type 'RequestInit' is undefined`.

Is there a way I can expose TypeScript's built in type definitions to make JSDoc aware of them? I have the JSDoc plugin configured for TypeScript. `settings.jsdoc.mode = "typescript"`

```
// @ts-check

/** @type {RequestInit} */
const FETCH_OPTIONS = {
  cache: 'no-cache',
  credentials: 'include',
  method: 'GET',
  mode: 'cors'
};

fetch('/api/getsomething/3', FETCH_OPTIONS)
 .then(nextFn)
 .catch(errorFn)
```

Comment: Have you tried an explicit type reference to `@types/react` like described here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html#-reference-types-

Comment: @DustInCompetent I tried with `/// <reference lib="dom" />` as that's where `RequestInit` is located and JSDoc remains unaware of these types.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell from the eslint plugin's [readme](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-jsdoc#eslint-plugin-jsdoc-rules-no-undefined-types), to define an external type for use in a JSDoc comment, you must either import and assign it to a variable (which isn't possible in this case), or declare it as "defined" in the rule's options like so:

```json
// .eslintrc
{
  "rules": {
    "jsdoc/no-undefined-types": [1, {
      "definedTypes": [
        "RequestInit"
      ]
    }]
  }
}
```